# How to strip quotes around Django generated html?

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to display a hyperlink in a form based on a value taken from a database. As far as I can tell Django doesn't support this natively, so instead I'm trying to generate the html manually.

In the modelform I'm overriding the init method:

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['hyper_change'] = forms.CharField(max_length=480)
        self.fields['hyper_change'].initial = f'<a href="https://website.com?sys_id={str(self.instance.change_id)}">{str(self.instance.change_id)}</a>'
```

The value is read in the template: `{{ change_formset.0.hyper_change.value }}`

The problem is that the generated html is quoted, so the complete string is displayed. Is there a way to strip the generated quotes? I've tried using a custom filter to replace the quotes, but that didn't work sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a string from the URL first and then run a string.replace('"', '') before setting it to fields initial.